# How do I remove the whitespace from between the bottom of my image and its border?

Tags: html, css, removing-whitespace

I'm trying to place an image in the top-center of my webpage.

I would also like it to have a 5px border.

Sounds simple enough, but there's a 4px high strip of whitespace I just can't shift.

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is a screenshot of the webpage and my code in its entirety:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUUrI.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>marioMafia - home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" id="randomLogo">
        <img src="miniMarioLogo.jpg" alt="randomLogo" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <style>
        #randomLogo {
            position: relative;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            max-width: 400px;
            border: 5px solid #333;
        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: The image I used in the screenshot had a 2:1 ratio but I had the same issue with a variety of sizes and ratios

Answer (score 1):

Set the vertical alignment of your image to top. E.g. `vertical-align: top;`

Comment: Sadly that didn’t work

Comment: Although [line-height: normal;] seems to do the trick

Comment: @PiggyTea12 Obviously it works https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/env6spo9/